# Empty Body on POST Request in Guzzle6/PSR7

Tags: php, guzzle6

I use Guzzle6 in the PSR7 flavor because it integrates nicely with Hawk authentication. Now, I face problems adding a body to the request.

```
private function makeApiRequest(Instructor $instructor): ResponseInterface
{
    $startDate = (new CarbonImmutable('00:00:00'))->toIso8601ZuluString();
    $endDate = (new CarbonImmutable('00:00:00'))->addMonths(6)->toIso8601ZuluString();
    $instructorEmail = $instructor->getEmail();
    $body = [
        'skip' => 0,
        'limit' => 0,
        'filter' => [
            'assignedTo:user._id' => ['email' => $instructorEmail],
            'start' => ['$gte' => $startDate],
            'end' => ['$lte' => $endDate],
        ],
        'relations' => ['reasonId']
    ];

    $request = $this->messageFactory->createRequest(
        'POST',
        'https://app.absence.io/api/v2/absences',
        [
            'content_type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        json_encode($body)
    );

    $authentication = new HawkAuthentication();
    $request = $authentication->authenticate($request);

    return $this->client->sendRequest($request);
}
```

When I `var_dump` the `$request` variable, I see no body inside the request. This is backed by the fact that the API responds as if no body was sent. I cross-checked this in Postman. As you can see, the body specifies filters and pagination, so it is easy to see that the results I get are actually not filtered.

The same request in Postman (with body) works flawlessly.

As the parameter be can of type `StreamInterface` I created a stream instead and passed the body to it. Didn't work either.

Comment: Really wouldn't recommend writing your own JSON. Create an array and use `json_encode()` instead

Comment: Yeah I had a hunch it's not how you do it. Thanks for the comment. Replaced by array now.

Comment: Still not working though, right :(

Comment: Nope... Unfortunately not. Tried that before as well. Digging through the Guzzle implementation, I cannot seem to understand what stream_for() does. And also not why RequestInterface is missing any method related to body or content...

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, actually my POST body is NOT empty. It just turns out that dumping the `Request` will not hint anything about the actual body being enclosed in the message.

I can recommend anyone having similar problems to use http://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/post_post to debug the POST body.

Finally, the problem was that my `content_type` header spelling was wrong as the server expects a header `Content-Type`. Because of this, the JSON data was sent as form data.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `JSON` requests can be created without using `json_encode()`... see the [documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://app.absence.io/api/v2',
    'timeout'  => 2.0
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', '/absences', ['json' => $body]);
```

Comment: I am using the PSR7 variant because it allows to easily integrate Hawk authentication. Your proposal would force me to use Guzzle's event system to enrich the request with an Authentication header.

Comment: @Chrisissorry there are several ways how one can create the requests, what's why I've added the term "simple". Didn't notice the wrongful `content_type` header at first, but this might not be interpreted as form data, but most likely as `text/plain` (such unrecognized headers most likely would be ignored).